# Creating an Sails.js Application on AWS AMI instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, node.js

So I followed the directions [here](http://sailsjs.org/#!getStarted) and created a sample application on a brand new linux machine.

No Apache, no anything, trying to use Node, express, etc to handle incoming http requests.

Sails says:

```
info: Server lifted in `/home/ec2-user/simKeynes`
info: To see your app, visit http://localhost:1337
info: To shut down Sails, press <CTRL> + C at any time.

debug: --------------------------------------------------------
debug: :: Fri Aug 16 2013 17:22:27 GMT+0000 (UTC)
debug: 
debug: Environment      : development
debug: Port             : 1337
```

but when I go to the associated IP address `http://54.214.44.52:1337/` I see nothing.

Checking Chrome's dev tools I see no response, and the browser displays:

```
Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 54.214.44.52:1337
```

This is definitively not the hello world page.

I have Node.js 0.10 running, a previous install of express, sails, mongo, mongoose, ruby, and that's about it.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the port in your AWS security group, and the virtual machine's firewall if applicable.

Comment: It was the AWS security group. Found it, fixed it, and hello world, baby! thanks!